# Creating Login System with Client Hash

Tags: php, html

I am working on building a simple login system, and I am stuck with trying to implement a safe system without sending the password over to the server.

I obiously have table is like:
USERID  |  USERNAME   | PASSWORDHAS  | SALT

My question is I am using sha256 to hash the password with a randomly generated salt. How can I grab the salt for that username without posting the form with the password?

I did something along this line to register the user:

```
    <script>
        function changeFormLogin() {
            var pass = document.getElementById('getPass').value;
            var username  = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var getSalt = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
            var hashpass = sha256(getSalt+pass);

            document.getElementById("hashedPassword").value = hashpass;
            document.getElementById("hiddensalt").value = getSalt;
        }       
   </script>
```

So typically I can now load a new page and grab the hiddenfields called "hashedPassword" and "hiddensalt". However in this case I am not sure what the salt is yet.

Comment: If I just post the form and only grab the $_POST["username"] will this send the password as "plaintext" or just the username? If I can do that I know how I could do this.

Comment: Normally [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is used to encrypt the data exchanges between the browser and the server. This way you can safely send the password from the browser to the server.

Comment: there's a `password_verify()` and `password_hash` in PHP. You can always uspublic/private key pairs in authentication although implementing that will be tricky. And provided the user will not lost their private key or give it to someone else